# MySQL: Insert multiple table value in one

Tags: php, mysql, insert

First time here.. and new to PHP MySQL.

I am trying to transfer WordPress user data to another table for some custom use. Here are the my tables

What I am looking can be find in rc_users (final result) table please see image with below link as I am new here and unable to post image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1yEc.jpg

Somehow I manage to insert value from wp_users table but now getting trouble to insert value from wp_usermeta table.

Also I want to convert wp_user_level on condition based so if user has `10` level than it will convert to `100` and so on..

Here what I have tried

```
// inserting user auth info                  
"INSERT INTO rc_users
(userid, name, password, email, created) 
SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass, user_email, user_registered 
FROM wp_users",     

// inserting user level info         
"INSERT INTO rc_users
(role)
SELECT meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE user_id = userid
AND meta_value = wp_user_level"
```

Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: do you want to insert all `meta_key` or just specific key?

Comment: I only want wp_user_level and should insert by checking userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join table `wp_user` with `wp_usermeta` to get the `meta_value`. Since the meta were saved by rows not columns, you need to pivot the result using `MAX()` and `CASE()`.

```
INSERT INTO rc_users(userid, created, email, name, password, `role`)
SELECT  a.ID, a.user_registered, a.user_email, 
        a.user_login, a.user_pass, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' THEN meta_value END) role
FROM    wp_user a
        INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b
            ON a.ID = b.user_id
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.user_registered, a.user_email, 
            a.user_login, a.user_pass
```

<sup>*I don't know why the value of role is 100 instead of 10 in your screenshot.*</sup>

```
INSERT INTO rc_users(userid, created, email, name, password, `role`)
SELECT  a.ID, a.user_registered, a.user_email, 
        a.user_login, a.user_pass, 
        CASE    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' THEN meta_value END) 
                WHEN 10 THEN 100
                WHEN 8 THEN 75
                ELSE 0
        END role
FROM    wp_user a
        INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b
            ON a.ID = b.user_id
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.user_registered, a.user_email, 
            a.user_login, a.user_pass
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing.. Can you explain query a bit for my knowledge? Also how can I cahnge the user_level value from 10 to 100? or what I want?

Comment: you mean multiply it by 10 to get 100? `MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' THEN meta_value END) * 100` ?

Comment: Not actually multiplication. I have different role values so for instance if value is 10 I need to change to 100 if it is 8 than 75 and so on..

Comment: This is just amazing.. You are genius...exactly what I wanted..I have one more query but post later in new question.. after give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using second Insert query you should use Update query

Update rc_users set role=(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = userid AND meta_value = 'wp_user_level');

Comment: I see, This is also nice idea. but isn't JW's code is more appropriate? and optimized? everything is done in one code?